# Microsoft Graph Permission not granted

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently working on a project for my work, and I intend to use Microsoft's planner API to help. I have granted the permission of Group.Read.All, and I get a warning of "Not granted for ". I've tried using my personal microsoft account to create the API, and attempted to access a planner created by me on that personal account as what I am accessing, and I get the same "permission denied error". How can I fix this?

Comment: To create a planner task you need to have Group.ReadWrite.All if you use a work or school account as shown in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-referencehttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference). You can also see personal account is not supported in the same document. Please also check if you are working with Work account you need to provide admin consent.

Comment: Are you still looking for help here?